# How to import Patternomaly into Ionic 2 project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, chart.js

I need to use Patternomaly in Ionic 2 project with Chart.js but I dont know how to import it.
Here is the github: https://github.com/ashiguruma/patternomaly
Can anyone tell me how to use it in typescript-ionic project?

Comment: not really, i still dont know how

Comment: are you using chart.js or ng2-charts ?

Comment: i am using chart.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**first**, install **`patternomaly`** via npm :

```
npm install patternomaly --save
```

**then**, import **`pattern`** from patternomaly in your chart component :

```
import pattern from 'patternomaly';
```

and **finally**, set the `backgroundColor` property for your dataset accordingly, as mentioned in the [doc](https://github.com/ashiguruma/patternomaly#available-patterns) :

```
datasets: [{
   data: [300, 50, 100],
   backgroundColor: [
      pattern.draw('square', '#1f77b4'),
      pattern.draw('circle', '#ff7f0e'),
      pattern.draw('diamond', '#2ca02c')
   ]
}]
```

see a [**working example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/doughnut-chart-sqtmif).